# How to know running services is finished?

Tags: android, service

I run service in main activity. This service calls class and this class do synchronize. But  how can I know synchronize finished . When synchronization is finished , I want to restart services . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can notify when the synchronization process ends using an implicit Intent, for example:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.yourapp.SYNC_COMPLETE");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

You will also need to register a BroadcastReceiver in your activity to intercept that Intent.

Comment: I am beginner . So can you give me fully tutorial link ?

Answer (score 0):

Few ways :
1. broadcast receiver ,as mentioned above
See :http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183
2. using a Bounded Service 
3. saving a SharedPreference/DataBase objects ,it will be updated usually using the Content Provider /CursorLoader